# How do I graph multiple items that are in the same dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I have a large dataframe with the columns "Time", "Batch", and "Value". I would like to graph all the batches on the same graph, but cannot figure out how to slide my data accordingly.

I have tried to

I have a DataFrame that is '3 x 4500', with about ~30 or so batches:

```
Time    Batch   Value
09/13/2018   B01    109.12
09/14/2018   B01    109.26
...
09/15/2018   B02    109.50
09/16/2018   B02    109.91
...
```

What I would like to do is graph them as a time series, with each line on the graph corresponding to a particular batch. Essentially making the x-axis the time, and the y-axis the value.

I isolated the first batch using the following:

```
batch01 = df.loc[df["Batch"] == 'B01']
```

...and I was able to graph that. What I am trying to do next, and please feel free to recommend an easier or more pythonic approach, is to iterate through the dataframe and create a new DF (like batch01) for each of the batches. This would essentially give me:

```
batch02 = df.loc[df["Batch"] == 'B02']
...
batch30 = df.loc[df["Batch"] == 'B30']
```

The ultimate objective is to be able to isolate each batch and graph it as a separate entity on matplotlib to see how they trend.

Comment: plot has an axis argument, so plot the first series and save the axis handle by doing `my_ax = batch02.plot(...)` and plot subsequent batches on that plot by doing `batch03.plot(..., ax = my_ax)`

Comment: The issue is that I would need to do this over and over for every batch (30 in this dataset alone). I am trying to find a way to automate this because I am expecting to have a few hundred at some point.

Comment: that's not your original question. You wanted to know how to do it, that's one way to do it *The ultimate objective is to be able to isolate each batch and graph it as a separate entity on matplotlib to see how they trend.*

Comment: Options are (a) loop through `df.groupby("Batch")` and create a plot for each group, (b) pivot the dataframe to have one column per batch and use a single call to `plot`. There are enough answers on those so I won't give another one here.